# Error getting array from Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am sending Array in `one activity` and getting that array in `other activity`.

Here is my code (Receiving side)

```
Bundle Extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(Extras != null)
{
    reports = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("reports");
    System.out.println("Size() "+reports.length);
}
```

but I am getting following Error

```
  07-16 18:15:27.628: W/Bundle(718):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
  07-16 18:15:27.628: W/Bundle(718):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 07-16 18:15:27.628: W/Bundle(718):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 07-16 18:15:27.628: W/Bundle(718):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 07-16 18:15:27.628: W/Bundle(718):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-16 18:15:27.628: W/Bundle(718):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 07-16 18:15:27.628: W/Bundle(718):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 07-16 18:15:27.628: W/Bundle(718):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 07-16 18:15:27.628: W/Bundle(718):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 07-16 18:15:27.658: W/System.err(718): java.lang.NullPointerException
 07-16 18:15:27.658: W/System.err(718):     at com.mythrii.timeapp.EditReports.onCreate(EditReports.java:41)
 07-16 18:15:27.698: W/System.err(718):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 07-16 18:15:27.698: W/System.err(718):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
 07-16 18:15:27.698: W/System.err(718):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
 07-16 18:15:27.698: W/System.err(718):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 07-16 18:15:27.698: W/System.err(718):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
 07-16 18:15:27.698: W/System.err(718):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 07-16 18:15:27.698: W/System.err(718):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 07-16 18:15:27.698: W/System.err(718):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 07-16 18:15:27.698: W/System.err(718):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-16 18:15:27.698: W/System.err(718):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 07-16 18:15:27.698: W/System.err(718):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 07-16 18:15:27.698: W/System.err(718):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-16 18:15:27.729: W/System.err(718):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anybody help me please.

Comment: Which line is EditReports.java:41?

Comment: System.out.println("Size() "+reports.length);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Bundle Extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(Extras != null)
{
    reports = Extras.getStringArrayExtra("reports");
    System.out.println("Size() "+reports.length);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you add some comments on your answer?

Comment: As u are getting getIntent().getExtras(); in Extras,you can get through Extras only instead of getIntent()

Comment: its still the same thing... no difference. I mean if it was crashing before, then it would still crash with your answer

Comment: what have to taken reports as?? the same as the one taken in previous activity from which setting intent

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are not getting any array (with key *reports*) from extra. You need to check if **reports** object is not `null` too.

```
Bundle Extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(Extras != null)
{
    reports = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("reports");

    if(reports != null)
        System.out.println("Size() "+reports.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use magic literals - use constants. Meybe you have misstype "reports" on ivoker side or forgot put extra there.
2. Are you sure that getStringArrayExtra returns something? No!
3. debug/add logs and check what extras contains.